# Why don't both expressions return the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this expression only overrides other elements from the array?

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
      const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? todo.completed = !todo.completed : todo
      );
      setTodos(updatedTodos);
    }
```

With the previous code, todos array only contains the elements completed and deletes all other elements.

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
      const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      setTodos(updatedTodos);
    }
```

While with this code all the array elements stay the same and only changes the completed element, which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: *... overrides other properties from the array?*  ->  I think you mean the array elements, not Array properties. Two very different things.

Comment: If `todo.id === id`, the first expression returns `todo.completed` and not `todo`.

Comment: *... all the array fields stay the same* ->  what are "fields"? Are these different things from "properties" (comment above)?  Do you mean the Array elements? And I assume it is an array of todo objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `.map()` is entirely based on what the callback function *returns*.  In the second example it's always returning the `todo` object.  But in the first example it's returning this:

```
todo.id === id ? todo.completed = !todo.completed : todo
```

This conditionally returns either the whole `todo` object or the result of this expression:

```
todo.completed = !todo.completed
```

The result of an assignment expression is the value which was assigned and only that value.  So while this expression is performing an assignment which modifies the `todo` object, that's of little consequence because that object isn't returned so `.map()` doesn't use it for anything.  It only uses the returned value.

---

This is reminiscent of a common *misuse* of the `.map()` operation.  It's meant to *project* an array into a new array, it is *not* meant for looping over an array to modify something in that array.  `.forEach()` or a simple `for` loop would be used for that.

---

As an aside... I recommend not using *either* approach in React like this.  While this is creating a new array to set state, just before doing so it's also *mutating* state.

Don't assign properties on `todo` at all.  Instead, return from the `.map()` callback a new object:

```
const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) =>
  todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
);
```

Comment: You've better explained what I was writing in an answer :) The only thing I'd add is that `map()` is being misused here; it's not supposed to be used to iterate an array. Either use a loop as intended or perhaps `find()` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , maybe he needs a new array? If you put the same pointer to array in a setState function it wouldn't really trigger rerender.

Comment: @AngelZlatanov: Indeed the OP does need a new array, but also needs to *not* mutate objects in the existing one.  Both of the approaches in the question float in a bit of a grey area between these two things, and should move overall to an entirely new array.

Comment: This whole map is unnecessary here.
You can just do it like this: const todos = todos.slice(); const index = todos.findIndex((t) => t.id === id); if(index !== -1) { todos[index].completed = !todos[index].completed }; setTodos(todos);

Comment: @AngelZlatanov Sure, `map` isn't the only way, but the way you showed using slice and findIndex is longer and even mutates an object in the state (a terrible practice).

Comment: @AngelZlatanov: That approach mutates state which shouldn’t be done in React.  The array itself may be new, but the object references are not.  Mutating an object in the new array also mutates it in the original array.

Comment: Let me be clear. You literally have no idea why this happened. It is because of the wrong use of the ternary operator and has absolutely nothing to do with the map method.

Comment: And speaking of terrible or good practice, if you are using this code aproach instead of const updatedTodos = arr.with(index, { ...arr[index], completed: !arr[index].completed }) which executes on average 10 to 12 times faster I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me correct first code based on your expected output, it will be self explanatory then,

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
  const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
    todo.id === id ? todo.completed = !todo.completed : todo
    return todo;
  });
  setTodos(updatedTodos);
}
```

If you still don't get it, here's the explanation: when you don't provide curly braces in fat-arrow functions, it will simply return the result of the expression you write (in your case it will always be `true`), so it was replacing the object in the array.

In the second part you're toggling the `todo.completed` and then returning the `todo`, so it is working fine.

Comment: This is essentially using the ternary conditional operator as a statement, a drop-in replacement for an `if` condition.  It's really not meant for this purpose and shouldn't be misused as such.  I'd even expect any decent linter to complain about this being an unused expression.  (Additionally, this approach is mutating state, which should be avoided in React.)

Answer (score -1):

Because in the first code you are actually returning 'todo.completed' if 'todo.id' is the same as 'id'.
In a code example you are basically doing this with the ternary operator:

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
 const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
  if (todo.id === id) {
   todo.completed = !todo.completed;
   return todo.completed;
  } else {
   return todo;
  }
 });
 setTodos(updatedTodos);
}
```

You might want to read about ternary operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator

Comment: The `else` block is unnecessary here, you can just have a single `return` statement outside of the `if` block.  (Additionally, this approach is mutating state, which should be avoided in React.)

Comment: @David , the question wasn't how to do it but what was the cause of it :))) So this code is meant to explain why it happens.